# Explain inference in Jena

Tags: jena, protege, inference, rdfs

In Jena, I have created an RDFS inference model using InfModel class:

```
InfModel infmodel = ModelFactory.createRDFSModel(schema, data);
```

Given an inferred statement from infmodel, how do we get the two statements that were used to infer it, similar to the the "explain inference" option in Protégé?  For instance, if `infModel` contains the statement `:a rdf:type :t`, we might get two statements used to infer it, e.g., `:a :p :b`  and `:p rdfs:domain :t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#derivations) (and testing with Jena 2.11.1) you can get access to a [`Derivation`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/Derivation.html) object which will allow you to create a textual description of what happened. In the following example, we retrieve [`RuleDerivation`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/RuleDerivation.html) objects that expose a little bit more regarding the internal state.

The following is a tested implementation of the documentation example which begins with the following model:

```
<urn:eg:C>  <urn:eg:p>  <urn:eg:D> .
<urn:eg:B>  <urn:eg:p>  <urn:eg:C> .
<urn:eg:A>  <urn:eg:p>  <urn:eg:B> .
```

... and the following rule:

```
[rule1: (?a urn:eg:p ?b) (?b urn:eg:p ?c) -> (?a urn:eg:p ?c)]
```

... to produce this resulting model:

```
<urn:eg:B>  <urn:eg:p>  <urn:eg:D> , <urn:eg:C> .
<urn:eg:A>  <urn:eg:p>  <urn:eg:D> , <urn:eg:C> , <urn:eg:B> .
<urn:eg:C>  <urn:eg:p>  <urn:eg:D> .
```

This basic transitive inference becomes the core aspect of the example to follow. Note that we obtain an instance of `RuleDerivation` which is a start towards your end goal.

```java
final Resource A = ResourceFactory.createResource("urn:eg:A");
final Resource B = ResourceFactory.createResource("urn:eg:B");
final Resource C = ResourceFactory.createResource("urn:eg:C");
final Resource D = ResourceFactory.createResource("urn:eg:D");
final Property p = ResourceFactory.createProperty("urn:eg:p");

final Model rawData = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
rawData.add(A, p, B);
rawData.add(B, p, C);
rawData.add(C, p, D);

final String rules = "[rule1: (?a urn:eg:p ?b) (?b urn:eg:p ?c) -> (?a urn:eg:p ?c)]";
final Reasoner reasoner = new GenericRuleReasoner(Rule.parseRules(rules));
reasoner.setDerivationLogging(true);
final InfModel inf = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, rawData);

final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
for (StmtIterator i = inf.listStatements(A, p, D); i.hasNext(); )
{
    Statement s = i.nextStatement();
    System.out.println("Statement is " + s);
    for (final Iterator<Derivation> id = inf.getDerivation(s); id.hasNext(); ) {
        final RuleDerivation deriv = (RuleDerivation) id.next();
        deriv.printTrace(out, true);
    }
}
out.flush();
```

The output of this example is:

```
Statement is [urn:eg:A, urn:eg:p, urn:eg:D]
Rule rule1 concluded (urn:eg:A urn:eg:p urn:eg:D) <-
    Rule rule1 concluded (urn:eg:A urn:eg:p urn:eg:C) <-
        Fact (urn:eg:A urn:eg:p urn:eg:B)
        Fact (urn:eg:B urn:eg:p urn:eg:C)
    Fact (urn:eg:C urn:eg:p urn:eg:D)
```

**EDIT - Tips**

Check out the internals of [`RuleDerivation#printTrace(...)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-core/2.11.0/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/RuleDerivation.java#RuleDerivation.printTrace%28java.io.PrintWriter%2Cboolean%2Cint%2Cjava.util.HashSet%29) if you are looking for an example about how to explore derivations. If you want to convert a triple (from `RuleDerivation#getMatches()`) back to a statement, use [`StatementImpl#toStaetment(Triple,ModelCom)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-core/2.11.0/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/impl/StatementImpl.java#StatementImpl.toStatement%28com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Triple%2Ccom.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom%29).

**EDIT2 - Done** Assuming that you are using one of Jena's built in rule-based reasoners, the following code will allow you to explore the matches for one particular derivation reported by a reasoner.

```java
final StmtIterator input = inf.listStatements(A, p, D);
assert( input.hasNext() );

final Iterator<Derivation> derivations = inf.getDerivation(input.next());
assert( null != derivations );
assert( derivations.hasNext() );

final RuleDerivation oneDerivation = (RuleDerivation) derivations.next();
final ExtendedIterator< Statement > matches = 
        new NiceIterator< Triple >()
        .andThen( oneDerivation.getMatches().iterator())
        .mapWith( new Map1< Triple, Statement >(){
            @Override
            public Statement map1( final Triple t )
            {
                /* Note that it seems that this model doesn't really mean anything. While
                 * the statement will be associated with the infModel, the triple that led
                 * to the match could have been from either the deductions graph or the
                 * raw graph. This does not actually add any triples to the underlying
                 * store.
                 */
                return StatementImpl.toStatement(t, (ModelCom)inf);
            }});
```

Comment: is there a way to create a rule involving mathematical operations, like sum or subtraction?

Comment: Yes, for example, you can use [`sum`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/builtins/Sum.html) and [`difference`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/builtins/Difference.html) to construct such rules.

Comment: @RobHall what is `Map1`? Can't get your code to compile because of this unknown class.

Comment: This compiles: `.mapWith( t -> StatementImpl.toStatement(t, (ModelCom)inf));`

Comment: [`com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.Map1`](https://docs.huihoo.com/jena/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/util/iterator/Map1.html) no longer exists. Apache Jena has since deprecated and removed functionality that Java streams has obviated. As you've demonstrated, [`NiceIterator.mapWith(...)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/util/iterator/NiceIterator.html#mapWith-java.util.function.Function-) now simply accepts a `java.util.function.Function`, which can be provided by lambda expression.