# How to perform Inference Explanation in Jena with a Pellet Reasoner?

Tags: jena, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

In protege, after synchronizing reasoner, we can find the **Explain Inference** function with this button:

[image: The Explain inference Button]

and then we can get the explanation like this:

[image]

The problem is, if I am using Jena with a Pellet reasoner, how can perform the same function with them?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194813/explain-inference-in-jena) on StackOverflow, but it seems like only works when dealing with native Jena reasoner rather than a third-party reasoner like Pellet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from looking at Pellet's source, the explanation module is OWL API specific, so it cannot be used with Jena.